# Encrypting/Decrypting a file using openssl through an autorun script

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

So I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a file using openssl. I am running it through a script that is automatically run when I mount a USB, and decrypts
the file. However, it doesn't work quite right, so here are my steps.

I encrypt the text file using...

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.txt.en -pass pass:123
```

I then have a script on the usb, which is automatically run when mounted.

**autorun.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
openssl aes-256-cbc -in file.txt.en -out file.txt -d -pass pass:123
```

Now it doesn't work when the USB tries to run it, however if I run it from console using...

```
./autorun.sh
```

It magically works and I am curious as to what the difference is. I also tried running it in interactive mode and that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: `it doesn't work` means what exactly? Is it not getting executed (validate by simple `echo "foo"` in that script) or are you possibly having user-issues (e.g. `autorun.sh` getting executed by a user that isn't allowed to run openssl)?

Comment: Can you clarify if `autorun.sh` is in the same directory as the file when you put it on the USB drive?  If you don't include the `autorun.sh` file in the same directory as the encrypted file, are you writing your script to point to the right file directory?

Comment: autorun is in the same directory as the usb. The script is being run by root, so it isn't a user level problem. It does get executed when I echo "foo"

Comment: You could `chown root autorun.sh` just to be sure. You could also do the same for the usb mount point. Never any harm in making sure mount point and file ownership is set in stone.

Answer (score 1):

The difference might be the directory it's executed from.
Maybe (probably) the system executes it not from inside the mount point with `./autorun.sh`,
but from somewhere else using an absolute path like `/media/mykey/autorun.sh`.

To make the script work when executed from a different directory, using absolute path, write this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
openssl aes-256-cbc -in file.txt.en -out file.txt -d -pass pass:123
```

Instead of testing this by unplugging and re-plugging, test like this:

```
cd /tmp
/path/to/mount/point/autorun.sh
```

If this works, then there's a good chance it will work after you unplug and re-plug.